# How to read 5 lines from a text file

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

How would I go about reading the first 5 lines from a text file in java using a buffered Reader or Scanner?  Here is my code

```
        final int assumedLineLength = 16;


    File file = new File("src/hw7p1/Acronyms.txt");
     HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>((int)(file.length() / assumedLineLength) * 2);
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    int linecount = 0 ;
    String eachLine = null;
    try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    for ( eachLine = reader.readLine(); 
            eachLine != null; 
            eachLine = reader.readLine()) {
        hashMap.put(eachLine, " ");
        linecount++; int i = 0;

    }


    TreeMap<String, String> sorted = new TreeMap<>(hashMap);

     Set<Entry<String, String>> sortings = sorted.entrySet();

    for(Entry<String, String> sort : sortings){ 
        System.out.println(sort.getKey() + " " + sort.getValue());

    }

     }catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

}
It prints out the text file, but what I am trying to do is just to get it to print out the first 5 lines. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: This code is correct, there must be an error in how you setup your reader.

Comment: Are you sure you are opening  a valid stream to a text file?

Comment: yes because I can get it to print from the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, don't use eachLine if you only want 5 lines.  Use

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  //read the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] readLines(int noLines, String path) throws IOException {

     FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
     String[] textData = new String[noLines];

     int i;

     for (i=0; i < noLines; i++) {

         textData[i] = br.readLine();

     }

     br.close( );

     return textData;

 }
```